# App Store receipt email, forwarded as attachment, won't open

Tags: mail.app, email

New user--just switched from Windows to an iMac running Yosemite. In the Mail app I use 'Forward as Attachment' a lot, with no problems.

However, I just forwarded an App Store email receipt as an attachment, and the recipient couldn't open the receipt. OS X identifies the attachment as a generic document (rather than an email) and can't find an app to open it. So far, this has only happened with the App Store receipt.

Is this problem likely due to something odd about the format of App Store receipts? If that's the case, I'll simply export those receipts to PDF and attach those files. Or is there something fundamental about attachments in Mail that I don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App store receipts are multipart mails, first part is `text/plain`, second is `text/html`. So in theory forwarding them should work just fine, in practice I see the same behavior you are seeing.

So either forward them directly (not as attachment) or print a PDF first (which might be kind of hassle depending on how often you need to do it).

Comment: I often get attachments that take quite a while to download, so accessing the file via webmail and/or saving the attachment (even on iOS) and then sharing it works well. Worst case, you can email the store and ask for another email with the receipt - and it's best to do that as soon as you realize the attachment is no longer viable.

Comment: I have accepted this response as the correct answer. It appears to be a quirk with the particular attachment, and not a case of "I don't know what I don't know yet. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

A iTunes receipt is simply html [I don't have an actual App Store receipt to compare, but I would imagine it's the same]

The header of the receipt itself is

> Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: QUOTED-PRINTABLE
>   Content-Disposition: inline
>
> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"><\html><\head>
>   <\meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Diso-8859-=
>   1">

<sup>…which is almost impossible to write out in markdown ;-) Ignore all the back slashes</sup>

Comment: You can try `<pre />` or `<code />` to output the special characters.

Comment: @bassplayer7 - I'm not great at html - first & last page I wrote was in 1992. Most welcome to try if you like [I had a quick fiddle & still couldn't get the remaining \'s out.]

Comment: I understand. It's what I do for a living. But I am on my phone, so I didn't have an easy way to edit myself. The IPhone doesn't do well with special characters.